# What is the best way to model the database of complex user interaction?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In my web application I will have users, each user will have albums, and each user will also have various users with permissions tied to an album.  I can't quite figure out if it would be more efficient to model my database with a bunch of tables prefixed by a user ID (i.e. 10384792_albums) or if I should have one table with a bunch of data inside (albums, which contains an id of the user).  My previous example was about albums, but relatively the same thing would apply for users of users.

Keep in mind, an album itself will likely have a lot of rows of data itself for instance a name, description, date created, etc.  I'm using MySQL and PHP.  I suppose this is more of a question where I want to be pointed in the way of good design concepts, something that is scalar without sacrificing the speed of receiving data.  Sorry if the question is a bit vague, I really don't know quite where to start, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: The users of users table is interesting.  Think of it this way: for every user on this website, they will have their own unique login form to where their clients can access specific albums.  The client will never log into my website using the same form that the users of my website do.

Comment: You definitely _don't_ want a separate table for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
User table
----------
ID (primary key)
Username
(more columns with more user info)

Album table
-----------
ID (primary key)
AlbumName
(more columns with more album info)
OwnerID (foreign key to User.ID)

AlbumPermission table
---------------------
ID (primary key)
AlbumID (foreign key to Album.ID)
UserID (foreign key to User.ID)
(more columns indicating permissions)
```

With this layout, you have Users and Albums as entities and a table linking them (many-to-many linking table) which contains permissions.  (This table is also sort of a meta-entity.  By itself it's essentially meaningless, but in the context of a User or an Album it contains information about the Albums that User can access or the Users which can access that Album.)

Each Album has a single User as its owner, and zero or more users linked in the AlbumPermission table who have various permissions associated with it.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment regarding tiered users, perhaps something like this...

```
Client table
------------
ID (primary key)
ClientName
(more columns with more client info)

User table
----------
ID (primary key)
ClientID (foreign key to Client.ID)
IsAdmin (boolean)
Username
(more columns with more user info)

Album table
-----------
ID (primary key)
AlbumName
(more columns with more album info)
OwnerID (foreign key to User.ID)

AlbumPermission table
---------------------
ID (primary key)
AlbumID (foreign key to Album.ID)
UserID (foreign key to User.ID)
(more columns indicating permissions)
```

The difference here is the addition of a Client table under which User records are grouped.  User records now have a foreign key to a Client record so that each user is a member of exactly one client (Client to User is one-to-many), and an `IsAdmin` field indicating if that User is an administrative-level user for that Client (that is, has the ability to create/modify User records for the Client).

It's expected that each Client would have at least *one* user.  It doesn't necessarily *need* one in this design, but it would make sense to create an initial User record when creating a Client (the User which is registering the Client).

You can expand this even further with more dynamic permissions for Client and User records, but this should be straightforward enough to get you going.

Comment: David, wonderful response.  Thank you.  But I should probably mention that the users of users will actually not be made up of users (the first table).  See, each user account on this website will have the ability to create users for their specific account.  For instance, every user on this website will have a login screen for their users to use.  Think of it as our users having clients, and they login through their own form.  Sorry, I probably should have addressed this...

Comment: @cereallarceny: You don't want to call both of these things Users then, it'll lead to further confusion.  I like the idea of having the parent called a Client and each Client can have multiple Users.  I'll update the answer...

Comment: Would this model still work assuming a user has multiple clients?

Comment: @cereallarceny: Depends on what you mean by a "User" and a "Client."  I think in your comment, User was the parent of Client.  In my design, Client is the parent of User.  You can swap the terminology either way you like.  Just make sure you're consistent.  On the other hand, do you need the child object to have multiple parents _and_ the parent object to have multiple children?  That is, are Clients and Users many-to-many?

Comment: I was thinking there would be one parent with multiple children.

Comment: @cereallarceny: In that case my second design in the answer should do the trick (though you can modify it further to suit your needs).  You can simply switch the User and Client concepts (table names and foreign key names on other tables) if you feel that User should be the parent and Client should be the child.  It all comes down to what the terms genuinely _mean_ to the business concept being represented.

Comment: Thank you David for all your help.  Green check well deserved.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure sounds good. 
I would say your relationships would look like this
usersTable->OneToMany->albumsTable->oneToMany->permissionsTable
Then the permissionsTable->oneToMany->usersTable 
That's the basic normalization based on key.
everything is indexed on pk - unless your joins are more complex that will be fine into millions of records. If deletes are part of the plan, have strategy for index optimization and ensure everything stays in memory.
Look at indexing permissionsTable (ie - pk, permission level) if elements other than pk are in the join.
Do you really think you need anything more complex?

If you are really concerned about snowballing in mysql look at a tcp proxy to use as a queue infront of mysql as it tends to handle concurrent requests rather poorly: see here http://flavio.tordini.org/a-more-stable-mysql-with-haproxy

Would recommend you not add complexity to your design due to overhead associated with it. Stick to the tried tested and true.